# Run app from Android Studio on LG Phone

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, lg

I am trying to run an app from Android Studio on my LG phone, but the device is not showing up.

The phone is an LG Optimus Zone 2
Model VS415PP
Android Version 4.4.2

I loaded the USB driver LG_VZW_United_WHQL_v2.22.0

Since I loaded the driver, I can see the device from my computer (running Windows 8), but I still cannot see it through the Android Studio.

I am a new learner to developing apps and using Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Did you [enable developer options on the device](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html#RealDevice)?

Comment: Yes, I enabled the developer options on the device.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure debugging is enabled on your device , connect your device with USB cable , open windows Command Line and run :

> ADB Devices

This will tell you if you have an ADB device connected .
If nothing showing up your pc is not recognizing the device .

Go to : Right click My Computer ----> manage ----> Device Manager ---->"The Device"

Right click on it and go to properties ----> Details ----> Hardware IDs

Copy the lines you see there and paste them in the file SOME_PATH\Android_usb.inf like this :

> // just an example
>
> %CompositeAdbInterface%   =  USB_Install, USB\VID_04E8&PID_6860&MI_01

And then try to install the drivers again by choosing the android_usb.inf file .
It should find the driver and install it  .

Comment: Debugging is running on device.

Device is connected with USB cable.

Hardware ID:
USB\VID_2341&PID_0043\9533534313635191D0A1
and it shows as an Unknown Device

The last step you recommended:
Copy the lines you see there and paste them in the file SOME_PATH\Android_usb.inf like this :

I'm not sure how to do this.  Do I find a file named Android_usb.inf or do I create this in notepad?

Need a little more guidance.

Comment: Try to look it under : 

C:\Users\yourUser\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf